# Delete a folder in project root from build.gradle in Module

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I use following task to delete a folder in current module :

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/generated/'
}
```

To delete from another module in the same project:

```
delete project(':test').file('build/')
```

What if I want to delete a folder in root project in build.gradle under a module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
delete "$rootProject.projectDir/build/"
```